# SortOrder by dropPrice Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop

there are default sort orders in PS 1.7 like >

```
(new SortOrder('product', 'price', 'asc'))........ 
(new SortOrder('product', 'date_add', 'asc'))->setLabel(    etc etc
```

but what I want to know is that is it possible to get SortOrder by Price drop? so that it will show product by `asc` or des DropPrice list, which should be like

```
(new SortOrder('product', 'dropPrice', 'asc'))
```

I want to filter it by "highest discounts & Lowest discount". so the page will show products with the highest amount of discount "`asc or dsc`" & vise versa.

Hope you all get my point.

Comment: any one? who can help?

Comment: Please provide enough code, some sample data and the desired results, then, others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem like a good idea.

Discounts usually depend on certain individuals, groups and categories.

With this method, you have to disable the PrestaShop cache feature or add very complex price display requirements to the system. Because the contents of the page must be reviewed and displayed for each user individually.